# SSD and corrupted master boot record

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, filesystem-corruption

I have a 120GB INTEL X25-M SSD as the main drive which boots windows 7 (about 2 months old). Recently my pc would hang randomly and boot only in repair mode. No automatic repair or recovery image would fix it. It will only boot if I used the `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` command in repair mode. This has happened already 3 times. I checked the drive for errors but it is healthy.

Is this normal? Do I need to return it?

Comment: Is there anything being recorded in the event log?

Comment: @ZianChoy, nothing except the event for the hang

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions from http://communities.intel.com/thread/12839?start=0&tstart=0 and since your drive worked fine for 2 months, I suggest:

1. Try wiping the disk with HDDErase ("for best results, connect it to the first sata port (sata0/port0), then go into the bios and set the sata controller to ide mode.  if there is an additional 'enhanced/compatible' setting, set it to compatible.")
2. Get a replacement drive if #1 fails.

Comment: I will give it a go and keep you updated.